# comparation of 2 binary numbers

Tags: c++, binary

I need to write program that will compare 2 binary numbers and return the result
I wrote this code using XOR, but idk how to improve my code, so for example 100101 and 101001 will return a < b. Can you help me fix this please?

```
string a,b;
    la = a.length();
    lb = b.length();

    int x = 0;
    if (la == lb)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < la; i++)
        {
            if (a[i]^b[i] == 1)
            {
                if(a[i] > b[i])
                    x++;
            }
            else {x--;}
        }
        if (x > 0)
            cout << a << " > " << b << endl;
        if (x < 0)
            cout << a << " < " << b << endl;
        if (x == 0)
            cout << a << " = " << b << endl;
    }
```

Comment: `X0Y < X1Z` regardless of what Y and Z are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this would be better
Here no need to iterate th whole string unless they are equal.
Just find the first '1' and the one which has 1 before will be bigger.
As simple as that

```
int main()
{
string a,b;
cin>>a>>b;
size_t aLoc=-1,bLoc=-1;
do
{
    aLoc = a.find("1",aLoc+1);
    bLoc = b.find("1",bLoc+1);
    if(aLoc<bLoc)
    {
        cout<<a<<">"<<b;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(aLoc>bLoc)
    {
        cout<<a<<"<"<<b;
        return 0;
    }
}while(aLoc==bLoc && aLoc!=string::npos);
cout<<a<<"="<<b;
return 0;
}
```

Edit:

aLoc give the position of 1 in first string, and bLoc for 2nd string
Lets take 1 exmaple

```
a = 10111000;
```

here first aLoc = 1 as the first '1' is at position 1

```
b = 10001100;
```

here bLoc = 1;

now for next iteration,
aLoc will be 3 as next '1' is at 3rd position

and bLoc will be 5 so naturally aLoc

which means '1' comes first in string a.

Hence

```
if(aLoc<bLoc)
   a>b;
```

Comment: If got it dont forget to mark the answer, if you think not yet optimised you can at least upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Let `a = 01, b = 10`.

In your program, in the first iteration, the value of `a[i]^b[i]` will be `1`. But `a[i] < b[i]` and you have not accounted for this case, thus the value of `x` remains `0`.

In the second iteration, again the XOR condition is true, and the condition `(a[i] > b[i])` is also true, thus incrementing the value of `x` to `1`.

After the loop, it will print `01 > 10` which is obviously false.

Modified Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    int la = a.length(), lb = b.length();
    int x = 0;

    // -1 if both are equal
    // 0 if a > b
    // 1 if b > a
    int flag = -1;
    // if you only want to check for equal length strings
    if (la == lb)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < la; i++)
        {
            if (a[i]^b[i] == 1)
            {
                if(a[i] > b[i])
                    flag = 0;
                else
                    flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
            std::cout << a << " > " << b << std::endl;
        if (flag == 1)
            std::cout << a << " < " << b << std::endl;
        if (flag == -1)
            std::cout << a << " = " << b << std::endl;
    }

}
```